QTreeView dotted rectangle around selected (or active) cell
I'm using QStandardItemModel to populate a QTreeView which contain more than a single column (i.e., a fusion of ListView and TreeView functionality). The problem is, no matter what I do, I cannot get rid of the dotted rectangle around the selected cell.

and here is the QSS:
QTreeView {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: @paperBackground; /* General background color */
    alternate-background-color: #ff4e4e4e; /* Alternate row color */
    color: #ffd0d0d0; /* Default text (foreground) color */
    border: 1px solid #444444; /* Optional border around the QTreeView */
}

QTreeView::header {
    background-color: @paperBackground; /* Header background color */
    color: #d0d0d0; /* Header text color */
    min-height: 10px; /* Set minimum header height */
    padding: 2px; /* Adjust padding if necessary */
    font-size: 12px; /* You can also reduce the font size to make it smaller */
}

QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: @paperBackground; /* Section background color */
    color: #d0d0d0; /* Section text color */
    padding: 4px; /* Adjust padding as needed */
    height: 10px; /* Force the height of each section */
    border: 1px solid #444444; /* Optional border for each section */
}

QTreeView::branch {
    background-color: @paperBackground;
}

QTreeView::item {
    background-color: @paperBackground; 
    outline: none;   
    color: #ffd0d0d0; 
    border: none;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 20px;
}

QTreeView::item:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

QTreeView::item:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ff3a3a3a;
    color: #d0d0d0;
}

QTreeView::item:selected:!active {
    background-color: #ff666666; 
    color: #e0e0e0;
}

QTreeView::item:selected {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #ff505050;
    color: #e0e0e0;
}    

QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: #ff3a3a3a;
    color: #ffd0d0d0;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ff444444;
}

QTreeView::verticalScrollBar, QTreeView::horizontalScrollBar {
    background-color: @paperBackground;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical, QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: #ff555555;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

I've tried altering the QSS to have the rectangle removed (mainly setting outline to none for various states of the QTreeView::item) to no avail.
The full code repository could be found here: https://github.com/NoMansQuest/VisualLinkerScript/

That's the focus rect's border, which is a standard visual aspect, and Qt does not currently handle it, as far as I understand. Meaning, there is currently no way to get rid of it. See QTBUG-4281 — Make it possible to remove the focus rect using style sheets...from 2009. Perhaps there is a workaround to blend its colors with the background's, if that thingy does not change its color to be visible no matter what...

See if these help you with that: How to change QComboBox's first item style when there is no selection, Qt Forum — How to remove focus rectangle on QListView and similar using QStyledItemDelegate with style sheets?, where Chris Kawa says: "Btw. the focus rectangle, ugly as it may be, is an important usability feature. Think twice before removing it.".

Somewhat unrelated tip: when debugging stylesheets, minimize them as much as possible (e.g., the handles and scrollbars are just noise here, also the sizes) while still producing the desired visuals. Also, avoid AI generated stylesheets when debugging, unless you understand what the combination they spit out will cause and affect, because they will make things messier, especially in "impossible" cases like these.

Actually if you won't include any "QTreeView::item" in the stylesheet, the dotted rectangle won't appear. You'll get a full-row rectangle for both hovering and selection (the desired behavior I'm after). The problem is the color, which is some spectrum of green.
However the moment you include "QTreeView::Item", then the dotted rectangle appears, and you loose control over how selection is done (it'll turn into 'cell' selection rather than 'row' selection, with all other settings being equal).
